# NPLogonNotify not called for smartcard login (Windows 7)

Tags: winapi, api, windows-7, smartcard

I have some code which acts as a network provider and can intercept both traditional logins and smartcard logins via the NPLogonNotify callback. This is running on XP (32 bit).

I am porting to Windows 7 (64 bit). NPLogonNotify is still supported according to MSDN and indeed my code captures traditional logins successfully. The issue arises when the smartcard login occurs. Unlike on XP, there is no callback into NPLogonNotify on Windows 7.

The question is: did this mechanism change in Vista/Windows 7 to explicitly prevent smartcard logins being captured in this manner? I have searched MSDN to no avail on this.

Any help gratefully received. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A registry entry called SmartCardLogonNotify has to be created as DWORD and set to 1, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\
Winlogon\Notify

This should resolve the issue